# How can I display a website's homepage on my own site?

Tags: php, ajax, wget, same-origin-policy, php-curl

I'm trying to create a portfolio website to showcase my talents as a web developer and drum up some extra freelance clients. To that end, I'd like to have a Bootstrap carousel of iframes that display the home pages of previous sites that I've worked on.

The trouble with this is that the external sites strictly adhere to the same-origin policy, and also lack any kind of CORS support. I no longer have any ability to change this as I no longer work for the web dev company that maintains these sites, so what would be the best way of accomplishing this task (preferably in PHP or AJAX, but I'm willing to consider any way that works)?

I have tried using wget/cURL to download local copies of the sites, but the mess of associated images, CSS files, etc. that need to be downloaded is not only a headache to maintain, but also takes ~2 minutes to download.

The external pages also contain a lot of relative paths to these resources, which need to be made absolute or pointed to my local copies of the resources, in order to work properly. This has become a much bigger task than originally anticipated, and I'm almost ready to just forget about the whole concept altogether. I'm therefore also open to any suggestions of how else I could advertise my previous work and show my skills to potential new clients. MTIA :-)

Comment: have you considered a carousel of screen-shots, possibly as links to the other sites...?

Comment: @thebjorn Yeah just started looking into url2png, but it's very expensive. Would you happen to know of any free alternatives? And BTW thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Nevermind, they actually provide a short list of their competitors on their own website!

Comment: Selenium can take screen shots (example code in many languages, including php, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks for that, although the other question that you linked to doesn't really provide a very thorough PHP example...how do I setup Selenium in the first place? Do I need the server? I've Googled these questions but Selenium seems to be a way over-complicated beast of a thing for what I think should be a very simple task...

Comment: Sorry, haven't used php for anything serious. Check out the Python example. (I'm assuming you'll have a cron job or similar, that generates the images outside of the request/response cycle).

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already figured it out after a few hours of Googling and trial and error. But have an upvote for the initial Selenium suggestion! :D

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be Selenium WebDriver, as suggested by @thebjorn in the comments above. It was rather tricky to get it fully working though, so for anyone stumbling across this in the future, here's how I eventually made it happen:

1. Download the latest version of [Selenium Standalone Server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) (requires Java 8+) and run it in a shell/cmd window with `java -jar <path to downloaded jar file>selenium-server-standalone-<version number>.jar`.
2. While you're on the above-linked site, also grab the latest WebDriver language bindings for your chosen programming language. Selenium provides bindings for Java, C#, Ruby, Python and Javascript (through Node.js). For third-party bindings for other languages, check out [this page](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/#thirdPartyLanguageBindings).
3. Extract the binding files to any location; I don't think it really matters where you put them as long as it makes sense to you, and that directory is easily accessible by your program.
4. Grab a copy of the latest [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) executable for your system (or the appropriate other-browser driver from the above-linked page) and add its location to your system PATH.
5. This is the hardest part, as it differs for every language and probably even each set of bindings within each language (if you went for a third-party option). But the code that worked for me in PHP, using the [Facebook WebDriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) bindings, is:

   ```
   use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
   use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

   // Ignore this line if you aren't using composer
   require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

   function getSiteSnapshot($siteUrl, $siteName) {
       $snapshot = __DIR__ . "/images/$siteName.png";

       $oneWeek = 604800;
       $lastModTime = !file_exists($snapshot) ? null : filemtime($snapshot);

       if ($lastModTime === null || $lastModTime < time() - $oneWeek) {
           $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
           $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
           $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);

           $driver->get($siteUrl);
           $driver->takeScreenshot($snapshot);
       }

       return $snapshot;
   }
   ```

Hope this helps another noob like me get used to using this very powerful web testing framework! Cheers! :-)